# Node.js: Why does post request w/ png have content-length header value that is smaller than the actual file size?

Tags: node.js, http, curl, post, content-length

I'm making a post request to a local node.js server. The post request contains a .png file that is 2.6 kB. The post request is issued using curl:

`curl -v -X POST -H "Content-Type: image/png" -d @node.png http://localhost:3000`

The request output of the curl command is:

`POST / HTTP/1.1
 User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
 Host: localhost:3000
 Accept: */*
 Content-Type: image/png
 Content-Length: 1328
 Expect: 100-continue`

Note that the Content-Length header is showing up as 1328 Bytes which is about half of the actual file size being posted. The content-length should be around 2.6 kB, correct? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It is actually request header for downloading a partial file.

please check out this from Wikipedia,

> The server has received the request headers and the client should
>   proceed to send the request body (in the case of a request for which a
>   body needs to be sent; for example, a POST request). Sending a large
>   request body to a server after a request has been rejected for
>   inappropriate headers would be inefficient. To have a server check the
>   request's headers, a client must send Expect: 100-continue as a header
>   in its initial request and receive a 100 Continue status code in
>   response before sending the body. The response 417 Expectation Failed
>   indicates the request should not be continued.

[Wiki Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)